# Filter on bindingSource for a datagridview doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, filter, bindingsource

I have 5 datagridviews, with 5 to 15 columns each...

So I'm trying to automate the filtering a little bit. But I just can't get it to work at all!

I My bindingSource uses A BindingList implementing Sortable : http://www.tech.windowsapplication1.com/content/sortable-binding-list-custom-data-objects

I've searched for a while but I can't find why I can set bindingSource.Filter, but it doesn't do anything :S

I've found examples for datatables or c# but I havent found some for Vb.net and BindingSource...

Here's my code where I create the binding soure, I've added the filter as a test, it ususlly isn't here.

```
Public Function reqTable(Of T)(ByVal pTable As String, ByVal pNoProjet As Integer, 
      Optional ByVal strAdditionnalConditions As String = "") As BindingSource
    Dim lstRetour As New cclSortableBindingList(Of T)(New List(Of T))
    Dim bsRetour As New BindingSource(lstRetour, "")

    rsRequestCSV = conSQL.Execute("SELECT * FROM " & pTable & " WHERE NoProjet = " & 
        pNoProjet & " " & strAdditionnalConditions)
    With rsRequestCSV
        While Not .EOF
            lstRetour.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(T), New Object() 
                 {rsRequestCSV.Fields})) 'New clsTable(rsRequestCSV.Fields))
            .MoveNext()
        End While
    End With
    bsRetour.Filter = "Quantite < 3"
    Return bsRetour
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the `BindingSource.Filter`, the underlying list (`cclSortableBindingList`) would need to implement the `IBindingListView` interface.  A `BindingList` doesn't implement this interface.

See [BindingSource.Filter Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter.aspx)  from MSDN.

Comment: Yeah I've guessed that, 

But I don't really want to implement IBindingListView on a BindingList by myself, there must be code somewhere where it's already done :S

Or is it really, simply a bad Idea to use binding list?

Because Most of the code is there (I've created Modele's class for about 6 tables :S) and I'd like not to start over again using dataTableCollection :S

Comment: I've tryed to implement the IBindingListView on top of the class i've had that implemented ISortable, but I couldn't achieve it easyly as least, 

So I've switched to DataSet / DataTables, works fine now, sorts, filter etc...